# Clarification on "this" pointer with multiple inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am a bit confused as to how the "this" pointer works with base and derived classes. Consider this code:

```
class A {
    //some code
};


class B:  public A {
    //some code
};
```

Is it correct to assume that the "this" pointer invoked from class B will be pointing to the same address as a "this" pointer invoked from some code in the base class A?

What about multiple inheritance?

```
class A {
    //some code
};

class B {
    //some code
};

class C:  public A, public B {
    //some code
};
```

Is it correct to assume that the "this" pointer invoked from class C will be pointing to the same address as a "this" pointer invoked from some code in the base classes A or B?

Comment: (1) No. (2) No.

Comment: In non-polymorphic `this` will always point towards the instance of the current class. So in `class C` when you refer to functions of either `A` or `B` then `this` might potentially change. In practice, in  simple cases like `class B: A` then `this` in `A` and `B` are  in the same place - unless there is some polymorphism going on.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. in case 1, if `B` is standard-layout then both `this` will have the same value

Answer (score 2):

> Is it correct to assume that the "this" pointer invoked from class B will be pointing to the same address as a "this" pointer invoked from some code in the base class A?

No, you cannot assume this. However, although not required, many implementations will use the same address (tested with `clang 11` and `gcc 10`).

With multiple inheritance, in your example, `clang 11` and `gcc 10` use the same address for an instance of `class C` and it's base `A`. The base `B` will have another address.

Another example is multiple inheritance with a common base instance:

```
struct A {};
struct B : virtual A {};
struct C : virtual A {};
struct D : B, C {};
```

Instantiating `D`, we get with `gcc 10` and `clang 11`:

```
D: 0x7ffc164eefd0
B: 0x7ffc164eefd0 and A: 0x7ffc164eefd0 // address of A and B = address of D
C: 0x7ffc164eefd8 and A: 0x7ffc164eefd0 // different address for C
```

There are no rules specifying the relations between addresses of instances of a derived and a base class. This is implementation dependent.

Comment: Thanks. What if in the above examples all classes A,B,C inherited from some common class "Common" (In the case of multiple inheritance above we can assume that both A and B virtually inherit from "Common") and the "this" pointer is always cast to a base pointer "Common *" before being used. Can we then assume that the casted this pointer will always be identical regardless of whether it is invoked from inside class A, B or C?

Comment: @astrophobia. Note that I meant: common base instance. When you inherit like A : virtual Common and B : virtual Common, there will be only 1 instance of Common indeed. The address of the instance of A OR B (OR none) may be the same as the address of the Common instance. static_cast<Common*>(pointerA) = static_cast<Common*>(pointerB)

Comment: @astrophobia It's east to check. Just write a function that prints the address.